# python argparse - passing list to argparse without command line

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to make use of an argument handler that I wrote using argparse from within another python script. I would like to call it by passing it a list of arguments. Here is a simple example:

```
def argHandler(argv):

    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test argument parser')

    parser.add_argument('foo', action='store',type=str)
    parser.add_argument('bar', action='store',type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-nee','--knightssaynee',action='store',type=str)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args.foo, args.bar, args.nee

if __name__=='__main__':

    argList = ['arg1','arg2','-nee','arg3']

    print argHandler(argList)
```

This returns a:

```
usage: scratch.py [-h] [-nee KNIGHTSSAYNEE] foo bar
scratch.py: error: too few arguments
```

It seems to me that the function that I define should take a list of arguments and flags, and return a namespace. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass those arguments to the `parser.parse_args()` method:

```
args = parser.parse_args(argv)
```

From the [`ArgumentParser.parse_args()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args):

> `ArgumentParser.parse_args(args=None, namespace=None)`
>
> [...]
>
> By default, the argument strings are taken from `sys.argv` [...]

Note the `args` argument there. You may want to make the `argv` argument to your `argHandler()` function default to `None` as well; that way you don't *have* to pass in an argument and end up with the same default `None` value:

```
def argHandler(argv=None):
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks, I just needed to change:
`args = parser.parse_args()` to 
`args = parser.parse_args(argv)` in my code

Answer (score -1):

another way i get input to program is from json file with key value pair and using json load library to load contents of file as json object.

Comment: And this has to do what exactly with the question?